# Animate a border color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following ajax call:

```
$('.provider_title_id').on('change', function(event) {
    var inp = $(this);
    var pk = $(this).data('pk');
    var id = $(this).val();
    $.post('/pid_item_update/', {'id': id, 'pk': pk}, function (response) {
        inp.css('border-color', 'green');
    });
});
```

This will make the border of the text input green. However, I would like it to just show a green "flash" and animate back to its previous border color. Something like this:

```
inp.css('border-color', 'green').fadeOut(1000);
```

The above would fade out the entire input, but how would I fade out the border color itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain it together with an animation back to the previous color. For example:

```
inp.css('border-color', 'green').animate({"border-color":"previous-color"}, 1000);
```